# cx_oracle errors out on multi threaded scenario - ORA 24550 error

Tags: django, cx-oracle

We are facing a very hairy issue while running a Django application with Oracle integration.

We are fetching quite a bit of data [around 2 MB] per query per page. When the user opens 5-6 pages at the same time, a ORA-24550 signal is shown at the Django console, and after that the django session dies with segfault. The error shown along with is either (KPEDBG_HDL_POP_FCPTR) or (KPEDBG_HDL_PUSH_FCPTR). After that even if we restart Django session, it gets killed automatically - for some time. After that the server gets back to normal.

This happens only for a multi-processor environment.
   We have been trying to debug this for few days now, and still to no avail. Exception handling doesn't work. We have added threaded=True in the OPTIONS - so as to make it multi-thread friendly. Nothing seems to work.

Other pages, which have less data, the issue is not there. This happens only for pages with 2 MB of data - which unfortunately - we have no way of avoiding.

The error is shown in both Ubuntu & CentOS. This issues doesn't seem to be there on the Windows machine. So there is a possibility that this is environment related.

Has anyone faced this issue before? If someone can help, it would be very helpful. We are all now bald pulling our hair out on this issue.

Regards,
Rajmohan H

Comment: do you find an answer to this? I have the same exact problem :/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the answer. I was testing this in Oracle XE. Once I moved away from XE, it started working properly. Also, we started using Oraclepool along with it - I now don't remember whether it was the oraclepool or XE move which got it to work, but together anyways it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot to add the answer earlier. I was testing this in Oracle XE. Once I moved away from XE, it started working properly. Also, we started using Oraclepool along with it - I now don't remember whether it was the oraclepool or XE move which got it to work, but together anyways it is working now

Answer (score 2):

You must add the instruction "threaded" in the "settings.py" file. like this:

```py
DB_QUALITY = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'instance',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxx',
    'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
    'PORT': '1521',
    'OPTIONS': {'threaded': True}
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': DB_QUALITY,
}
```